# responsive layout styles not being consistently applied when reopening the live server

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive, responsive-images

I am able to make a little responsive layout for mobile at 374px.I adjusted all the headings,text font-size according to the mobile layout.The problem is that when i close the live server and then open it again,my desktop layout is okay but my mobile layout's element become too small including the heading, text, and logo .untill or unless I undo and redo a same certain properties. such as in phone.css file I mentioned (font size:5rem;) in (section-text h2 selector).when i close and open the live server again i need to remove and rewrite this property in order to get a proper mobile layout which i did initially.

How to solve this.

[Desktop layout is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91gGC.png)

Problem is in mobile layout below are the images

[Here is the image what i expected to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlEIq.jpg)

[Here is the version of what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBUs7.png)

[This is what is happening when i close an reopen the live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui0ZK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.